# Access to USB device denied

Tags: permissions, usb

I have a [ColorHug ALS](https://hughski.com/colorhugals.html) ambient light sensor that I use together with the DDC/CI interface of my display to automatically set the brightness of my displays just like every smartphone does. It is connected via USB:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 273f:1007 Hughski Limited
…
```

This has been working fine until a few weeks ago, some Fedora upgrade likely has changed something. I have a file `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-i2c-permissions.rules` which contains this:

```
KERNEL=="i2c-[0-9]*", GROUP="i2c", MODE="0660"
```

Also my user account is in the `i2c` group. Also all these devices should be readable for my user:

```
$ ls /dev/i2c-* -l
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 0 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-0
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 1 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-1
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 2 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-2
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 3 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-3
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 4 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-4
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 5 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-5
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 6 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-6
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 7 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-7
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 8 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-8
crw-rw----. 1 root i2c 89, 9 26. Dez 10:41 /dev/i2c-9
```

But now I get the following when trying to get a reading from the device:

```
$ colorhug-cmd take-reading-raw
No connection to device: USB error on device 273f:1007 : Access denied (insufficient permissions) [-3]
```

Calling this as `root` still works, so it is just a permission problem.

Why does the permission not get passed to my normal user account and how can I restore that?

Comment: Did you try to `cat /dev/i2c-0` e.g. to check if permissions are OK? Maybe another device is involved beside `/dev/i2c-*` and you could `strace -o /tmp/colorhug.strace colorhug-cmd take-reading-raw` and look into `/tmp/colorhug.strace` to see what goes wrong.

Comment: I have just tried that, there is no `i2c` anywhere in the trace. But it went through just fine. Apparently all was needed was a restart. I guess I should delete the question then as it is not reproducable.